# How to select and create a dynamic event click listfragment in android

Tags: java, android, dynamic, tabs, android-listfragment

I need to create events for clicking the checkbox, but it only takes effect for the first screen. My code :

Would be very happy if someone help me up.

```
public class ListaFragment extends ListFragment{


    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        //ListView lv = getListView(); // here it is available

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container, false);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();



        // get all songs from sdcard
        Button exe = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Execultar);
        exe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SongsManager novo = new SongsManager();
                this.list = novo.getPlayList();         



                CheckBox android = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (v.isClickable()){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cliquei", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                });

                //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                //CheckBox android = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


                //CheckBox ck = (CheckBox) v;

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cliquei "+i+'-'+android.isChecked()+'-'+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });


        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }



        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(), songsListData,
                R.layout.fragment_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

         setListAdapter(adapter);   

         return rootView;

    }

}
```

Is everything right with the code? What are the changes that I have to make in the code to achieve the task that I am looking for.

Comment: You are not setting the click listener on your checkbox until the user clicks on your `exe` button. Is that intentional?

Comment: actually my intention is that for every line of an event click being listview, listview the bears from sd, the way i did it takes effect only first line of the list, do not know if i could be clear ...

Comment: want to consider not only when you click the button...

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question. Does each view in your list contain a single checkbox, or several?

Comment: several, as below, a list of checkbox.
item 1 - not checked
item2 - checked
item3 - not checked
item4 - not checked
if I score the second item, nothing happens. only happens when I click the primero.
it applies only click on the first item on the screen.
this list is within a fragmentlist

sorry for my bad english, thank you for your patience

Comment: You only set a click listener on the first checkbox (`(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);`). If you want to receive events from each checkbox, you will need to iterate through and apply a click listener to each one.

Comment: I'm pretty lost it, you could quote me an example of how to check each line?

Comment: It all depends on your layout, which I don't entirely understand. Maybe you could post the xml for your root view `R.layout.fragment_lista`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/66z1ly4niaol6y4/xml.rar

Comment: Fragmentlist and fragmentitem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreateView` you are setting a click listener on the first checkbox in the list. At this point in time there is no way to know how many items will be in your list or iterate through them, so you are going to want to remove that part of your code. I can suggest two possible solutions.

The first is much simpler, but with one major drawback. You will not be able to tell if they clicked on the check box, or the song title. If that is not a problem for you, this is the easiest solution. Attach an `OnItemClickListener` to your listview. It will tell you which row in the list was clicked.

```
// get our list
ListView listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

// set the click listener on the whole list
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (view.isClickable()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cliquei row # " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

If you *need* to know that they are clicking on the checkbox specifically, then you will have to do a little extra work. Instead of using a `SimpleAdapter` you are going to want to make your own adapter class that extends `SimpleAdapter`. Inside your new adapter class you will override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. This method will be used to create each view in your list. As the list view is created, you will attach an `OnCheckedChangeListener` to the checkbox on that particular view. Something like the following...

```
public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleListAdapter() {

    @Override
    public view getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // let the superclass inflate our view for us
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // attach a listener to our check box
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "row # " + position + " is checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "row # " + position + " is unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```